# cocos2d delegate question

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

in the main.m file:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppController");
[pool release];
return 0;
```

}

I just add the cocos2d sample test code to my project, and there're so many AppController delegate in those files.

So how can I know which "AppController" of delegate is used?

Comment: Some article of cocoa framework said 
The info is stored in MainWindow.xib file which a cocos2d doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

The project for cocos2d example has a lot of build targets.

Scroll down in the Groups & Files pane on the left, until you find the "Targets" group.

Unfold that and look at the individual targets.

All the actual example code uses "...Test" as a name.

When you check in one of the build targets, it will have a group named "Compile Sources" which holds the files that will be compiled for that target.

In the .m file you find there, you will find the implementation of "AppController" used for this target.